# Remote Desktop from Mac OS X to Windows 7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, macos, remote-desktop

Does Mac OS X have a native remote desktop client to connect to Windows 7 machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoRD: http://cord.sf.net

Microsoft Client: https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id715768417

I'm biased towards CoRD...

Answer (score 3):

You can download an official Microsoft Remote Desktop Client or use an app called CoRD which is based around the open source RDesktop: