# Accessing Windows work computer with home MacBook Pro laptop

Tags: windows-7, macos, remote-desktop

What is the best way to access my Windows-based computer at my office from my MacBook Pro laptop at home?  My law firm's' IT guy tells me to use Windows 7 Remote Desktop Connection, but that clearly does not work for my Apple laptop since it runs OS X Yosemite v 10.10.1
(I dont' know the name of the Windows server used at my firm, but email and file documents in ProLaw are accessed through Citrix Receiver which I used to be able to log into, but no longer can.)

Comment: *"that clearly does not work for my Apple laptop since it runs OS X Yosemite v 10.10.1"* Here you go: https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id715768417

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remote Desktop from Mac OS X to Windows 7 Pro](http://superuser.com/questions/199855/remote-desktop-from-mac-os-x-to-windows-7-pro)

Answer (score 0):

Since you referred to Windows 7 Remote Desktop, that should essentially be the same as Teamviewer. Is that not a viable option? (Sorry I cannot comment on your question yet as I do not have the rep to do so)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend teamviewer as well (you can find it on http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx). It is a desktop sharing tool and works fine on MacOS and Windows. I use it myself to access my Windows desktop pc from my MacBook when im at university.